# Javascript rremove any non-alphanumeric string except space

Tags: javascript

my code is

```
val.replace(/["']/g, "").replace(/[~[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+~]/g, "");
```

but, that code cannot remove text like this sfsfS@$@$2f

Answer (score 1):

already got it

```
input.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
```

thanks